# Ubuntu 16.04 Wifi Driver mysteriously disappearing, again

Tags: drivers, 16.04, lxde, chroot, boinc

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 with LXDE, LXQt, and Ubuntu desktop, with BOINC Enigma@Home actively running. My WiFi did not work when I first started the LiveUSB, and when I restarted the LiveUSB magically worked again. After I installed the OS, the same happened, except that now the WiFi doesn't work after several chroot updates from the LiveUSB "savior" and reboots. The only proprietary driver not in use is one concerning my AMD CPU that can't be put to use because I lack internet... Please help, Here are the outputs of some stuff:

Here is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 05
       serial: 74:46:a0:c8:cc:4e
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:26 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 01
       serial: 2c:d0:5a:2a:a2:d9
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-21-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.68 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:f0200000-f027ffff memory:f0280000-f028ffff
```

And here is an error when looking at my Network connections in Settings --> Network:
[image: Error Message]
Please note how the internet icon is now longer in the top right corner of my screen...

There are currently no updates are available through `sudo chroot`:
[image]